# Nature of InputStream.read() method against URL stream

Tags: java, url, buffer, inputstream

During my internship I encountered a codepiece (it turns out to be default codepiece for this matter) shown below.

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
```

So here are my questions.Assume the data is 2050 Byte

1. What is the reason of using 1024 constant?
2. As I took Computer networks class,I can relate some of my knowledge
   to this
       matter.Assuming we have fast connection, will we read 1024 Byte long
       data at every iteration? So will count variable be 1024,1024,2 with
       every iteration or is it possible 1000,1000,50 ?
3. If we have really
       slow connection , is it possible that read() method will try to fill
       1024 Byte buffer , even if it would take minutes long?

Comment: @BorisTheSpider No, it will not block until the read buffer is full. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP absolutely right. Minor brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason of using 1024 constant?

None. It's arbitrary. I use 8192. The code you posted will work with any size >= 1.

> Assuming we have fast connection, will we read 1024 Byte long data at every iteration?

No, you will either get an exception or end of stream or at least 1 byte on every iteration.

> So will count variable be 1024,1024,2 with every iteration or is it possible 1000,1000,50 ?

Anything >= 1 byte per iteration is possible unless an exception or end of stream occurs.

> If we have really slow connection, is it possible that read() method will try to fill 1024 Byte buffer, even if it would take minutes long?

No. It will block until it reads at least one byte or an exception or end of stream occurs.

This is all stated in the Javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

I/O operation are expensive , so it is generally recommend to batch it, so in your case it is 1KB you can change that to more/less depending on your requirement.
You have to remember that it is blocking call , so it is too big you might get impression that your program is not moving.

You should not read byte by byte also because it is too much of I/O operation and program will spent all time in I/O only, so size should be depend on rate at which you can process data.

Comment: Doesn't answer the questions that were asked.

Comment: agree that answer were not in bullet point but it was good enough to answer the question.